# equivalence relation proof for all positive integers

Tags: equivalence-relations

The relation $R$ is defined for all positive integers such that $(a,b) R (c,d) \longleftrightarrow a+d=b+c$. Show that $R$ is an equivalence relation.

Comment: Which are three conditions to satisfy to get an equivalence relation?

Comment: [Also](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106295/equivalence-relation-on-mathbbn-times-mathbbn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For R to be an equivalence relationship it would have to suffice all the following conditions :

1) it has to be a reflexive relationship ! ( (a,b) R (a,b) )

2) it has to be simetric ( (a,b) R (c,d) only if (c,d) R (a,b) )

3) it has to be transitive ( if  ( a,b) R (c,d) and (c,d) R (e,f) then (a,b) R (e,f) ) ;

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: If you need a step by step demonstration i can help you with it!

Comment: That would be really nice :)

Comment: Firstly we have to prove that every pair (a,b) is in relationship with itself.
You defined R as :two pairs : (x,y) (z,t) are in the relationship R if (x + t) =(y + z)

1)Applying the definition of this relationship on the pairs (a,b) , (a,b) 
we get that (a+b)  = (b + a) which is true. As suchs (a,b) is in the R relationship with (a,b) => R is simetric.


2)We presume the pairs (a,b) are in relationship with (c,d) ((a + c) = (b + d)

We have to show that (c,d) is in a Relationship with (a,b); => (c +a ) = (d + b) .Because + is commutative ( a + c = c + a ) the equality is true.

Comment: 3) We presume (a,b) is in a relationship with (c,d) and (c,d) is in a relationship with (e,f);

from the first relationship        (a+c) = (b+d) ;
from the second relationship  (c+e) = (d+f);
now you have to show that ( a + e )  =  ( b + f).

Comment: Thank you, I got it.This was so helpful :D

Comment: The first step is showing the reflexivity, right? not simetry. The second step is for simetry.

Comment: Yes,that s right! My bad :(

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\left( a,b\right) R \left( c,d\right)$ if and only if $a-b = c-d$.

Comment: How far does this go toward showing $R$ is an equivalence relation?  You've rewritten the definition, but made no mention of reflexivity, symmetry, or transitivity.  Please review [How do I write a good answer?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: From this all the necessary properties are evident, because instead of calculating anything, one just considers the property "difference of coordinates" which is evidently equivalence, i.e. from a two-dimensional problem it shifts to a one-dimensional.